# How to update my working Git branch from another branch (develop) ? using github Desktop App

Tags: github-desktop

Wanna know how to update feature branch with respect to base branch (i.e. development)
I don't wanna use commands; so that's why I prefer Github Desktop

Suppose I have the following branches

```
master
development
API-Integration
```

Now I have finished my changes on the API-Integration branch and if someone committed changes on the development branch, then how can I update my feature branch (API-Integration) ;

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below steps. Adding the link with screenshot as well for your reference.

1. In GitHub Desktop, click  Current Branch.
2. Click Choose a branch to merge into BRANCH.
3. Click the branch you want to merge into the current branch, then click Merge BRANCH into BRANCH.

[Github desktop merge branches](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/keeping-your-local-repository-in-sync-with-github/syncing-your-branch#merging-another-branch-into-your-project-branch)